# Implementing database caching in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, caching

I'm considering implementing sql database caching using the following scheme:

1. In the ASP.NET webapplication I want a continuously running thread that check's a table, say dbStatus, to see if field dbDirty has been set true. If so, the local in-memory cache is updated, querying a view in which all needed tables are present.

   2. When any of the tables in the view is updated, a trigger on that table is fired setting dbStatus.dbDirty true. So this would mean I have to add a on insert,update,delete trigger on those tables

One of the reasons I want to implement such a caching scheme is that the same database is used in a Winform version of this application.

My question: is this a viable approach?

Many thanks in advance for helping me with this one, Paul

Comment: Have you considered creating a SqlDependency on the view result?  That would eliminate the need for triggers and the dbDirty flag,

Answer (score 0):

This is a viable approach.

The main problem you need to be aware of is that ASP.NET worker processes can exit at any time for many reasons (deployment, recycle, reboot, bluescreen, bug, ...). This means that your code must tolerate being aborted (in fact just disappearing) at any time.

Also, consider that your app can run two times at the same time during worker recycling and if you run multiple servers for HA.

Also, cross-request state in a web app requires you to correctly synchronize your actions. This sounds like you might need to solve some race conditions.

Besides that this approach works.

Consider incrementing a version number instead of a boolean. That makes it easier to avoid synchronization issues such as lost updates because there is no need to reset the flag. There is only one writer. That's easier than multiple writers.

Comment: Thanks usr! What I intend to do is using a Mutex in the routine (say FillThread), that is called to retrieve the data. Also in the routine that is called to present the data from the view (ViewData) I intend to do a check whether the thread is still running and restart it as needed. I'm not sure about the incremented version number instead of a boolean. I'm also considering using a stored procedure to both return the viw data and to handle dbDirty. In this application whith a web-version and a Windows form-version there will be multi-writers (or do you mean something else??)

Comment: `restart it as needed` why would it exit? Wrap the thread in `while (true) try-catch` to keep it alive in the presence of bug. Log the bugs.

Comment: What about the following scheme: Maintain the version number as proposed. Cache data with the version number as the key. When you want to display something you get the version from the db and then use the cache keyed by that version. That results in easy code and full transactional consistency for the data.

Comment: I'm unclear about your general approach, though. Not sure where the Mutex fits it. It's all very suspicious. My spider sense is tingling... :)

Comment: I agree wrapping it in try-catch would do it (but, to be on the safe-side...) The Mutex avoids multiple data retrieval for one and the same cached datatable. Spider sense at ease?

Comment: If your app runs multiple times in parallel, as mentioned above, only one instance might see the dirty flag. The cache invalidation will not happen with the other instance. Does the winforms app also monitor the dirty flag? Does the web app also edit data and set the flag?

Comment: Well, the Web application services multiple users. The Winform application too. The tables will be modified from both the Web application as the Winform application -all within a multi-user environment-. So, if a user modifies a record in say table A (which is included in the View), than the trigger on table A will set dbDirty in table dbStatus.

Comment: On the web application, this dbDirty field is monitored and de data from the view is only retrieved when dbDirty is set, if dbDirty is not set the cached view data is returned. So setting dbDirty is only performed from triggers on the tables, so it's only set from the SQL Server database server. Ofcourse this requires a single-caching scheme on the web application.

Comment: And by what mechanism is the dirty flag reset? I already pointed out race conditions in this scheme. Not sure why you don't want to go for the sequence number. Solves all those races and edge conditions.

Comment: the dirty-flag reset should be a part of the stored procedure by which the web application retrieves the view data. I'm still thinking on this: I'm not saying a version-counter instead of a dirty-flag would be better. Avoiding a race-condition on the web application by using a single-caching scheme and guard it with a mutex. Whether an update to one of the tables is done from the Winform or Web application, the dirty-bit or counter gets updated and the web application 'knows' it needs to retrieve fresh data

Comment: There might be two web apps during recycling... Also, does the WinForms app not need new data as well?

Comment: Do you know of a way to detect recycling? The Winform does not use the view. Btw: thanks for your time sofar!

Comment: Design your scheme so that recycling does not matter. You're down the wrong path. You're thinking of an ASP.NET app as an exe that just runs. It's more dynamic than that. Web apps should be as stateless as possible and ideally assume little about other apps using the same data stores.; Also, do you not need two instances for HA behind a load balancer? It's uncommon to run a production app on one machine only.

Comment: I'm starting to think you're right. Thanks for your thoughts and input. Kind regards, Paul